# Issues while using jasperreports Java bridge and symfony

Tags: php, symfony, jasper-reports, php-java-bridge

I'm building a web application using symfony 2 php. And I want to generate some reports using jasperreports. I used Java Bridge and I have the Java bridge war deployed in my tomcat 7 but when I try to generate my reports I face an error.

So here is my code in my controller

```
 require_once("http://localhost:8080/JavaBridge/java/Java.inc");
 $reportsPath ="D:/jaspertest/";
        $reportFileName = "report";
        $jasperReportsLib = "D:/Programmes/jasperReport/lib";
        $java_library_path = '';
        $handle = @opendir($jasperReportsLib);
        while(($new_item = readdir($handle))!==false) {
            $java_library_path .= 'file:'.$jasperReportsLib.'/'.$new_item .';';
        }
        java_require($java_library_path);
       $sJcm = new JavaClass("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager");
        $report = $sJcm->compileReport($reportsPath .$reportFileName.".jrxml");

    $map = new Java("java.util.HashMap");
    $emptyDataSource = new Java("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JREmptyDataSource");
    $sJfm = new JavaClass("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager");
    $print = $sJfm->fillReport($report,$map,$emptyDataSource);
    $sJem = new JavaClass("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperExportManager");
    $sJem->exportReportToPdfFile($print, $reportsPath .$reportFileName.".pdf");
    set_time_limit(0);
    @readfile($reportsPath .$reportFileName.".pdf");// or die("problem occurs.");
    $response = new Response($reportsPath .$reportFileName.".pdf");
    $response->headers->set('Content-type', 'application/pdf');
    $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 'attachement; filename=Report.pdf');
    $response->headers->set('Cache-Control', 'must-revalidate');
    return $response;
```

And here is the exception I get:

```
Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException: Notice: fwrite(): 
    at n/a
        in http://localhost:8080/JavaBridge/java/Java.inc line 482

    at Symfony\Component\Debug\ErrorHandler->handleError('8', 'fwrite(): ', 'http://localhost:8080/JavaBridge/java/Java.inc', '482', array('data' => ''))
        in  line 

    at fwrite(resource, '')
        in http://localhost:8080/JavaBridge/java/Java.inc line 482

    at java_SocketChannel->fwrite('')
        in http://localhost:8080/JavaBridge/java/Java.inc line 528

    at java_SocketHandler->write('')
        in http://localhost:8080/JavaBridge/java/Java.inc line 671

    at java_HttpHandler->redirect()
        in http://localhost:8080/JavaBridge/java/Java.inc line 743

    at java_Protocol->redirect()
        in http://localhost:8080/JavaBridge/java/Java.inc line 755

    at java_Protocol->finish()
        in http://localhost:8080/JavaBridge/java/Java.inc line 794

    at java_Protocol->invokeEnd()
        in http://localhost:8080/JavaBridge/java/Java.inc line 359

    at java_Client->invokeMethod('0', 'updateJarLibraryPath', array('file:D:/Programmes/jasperReport/lib/.;file:D:/Programmes/jasperReport/lib/..;file:D:/Programmes/jasperReport/lib/jasperreports-5.6.0.jar;file:D:/Programmes/jasperReport/lib/jasperreports-applet-5.6.0.jar;file:D:/Programmes/jasperReport/lib/jasperreports-fonts-5.6.0.jar;file:D:/Programmes/jasperReport/lib/jasperreports-javaflow-5.6.0.jar;', 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/', 'C:\wamp\www\syslife_v1\web', '.;C:\php\pear'))
        in http://localhost:8080/JavaBridge/java/Java.inc line 986

    at java_require('file:D:/Programmes/jasperReport/lib/.;file:D:/Programmes/jasperReport/lib/..;file:D:/Programmes/jasperReport/lib/jasperreports-5.6.0.jar;file:D:/Programmes/jasperReport/lib/jasperreports-applet-5.6.0.jar;file:D:/Programmes/jasperReport/lib/jasperreports-fonts-5.6.0.jar;file:D:/Programmes/jasperReport/lib/jasperreports-javaflow-5.6.0.jar;')
        in C:\wamp\www\syslife_v1\src\MamdaIT\ComptabiliteBundle\Controller\BordereauController.php line 372

    at MamdaIT\ComptabiliteBundle\Controller\BordereauController->editionDetailBordereau(object(Request), '66')
        in  line 

    at call_user_func_array(array(object(BordereauController), 'editionDetailBordereau'), array(object(Request), '66'))
        in C:\wamp\www\syslife_v1\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel.php line 144

    at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(object(Request), '1')
        in C:\wamp\www\syslife_v1\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel.php line 64

    at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(object(Request), '1', true)
        in C:\wamp\www\syslife_v1\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareHttpKernel.php line 69

    at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareHttpKernel->handle(object(Request), '1', true)
        in C:\wamp\www\syslife_v1\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel.php line 185

    at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle(object(Request))
        in C:\wamp\www\syslife_v1\web\app_dev.php line 30
```

I looked everywhere but I couldn't find a solution, am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple problems here, but I'll try to explain step by step:

**1. The code part.**

You should not use `java_require` to dynamically add library dependencies from PHP (has been removed from v6).

**2. Error reporting**

As you noticed the symfony error handler couldn't provide very helpful information (no clear message). Not a symfony problem, but more about the way exceptions/errors are handled by the `Java.inc` client. The bridge exceptions (java bridge side) must be retrieved explicitly using `getLastException` (*not 100% correct, but let's assume it to make things simple*). Of course no error handler (symfony, whoops...) has support for this.

---

So what to do ?

**1. Fix registration of your java libs**

Your dependencies must be either provided in the war bundle (what is often called the *JavaBridgeTemplate.war*) or in the tomcat global `lib` directory.

Personnally I prefer the first method to prevent possible collisions and it can be achieved by either:

- adding the jar's into your WEB-INF/lib directory inside the war file and redeploy (*this is generally how it was done by most php devs*).
- Or another option (*totally opinionated and based on a [javabridge fork](https://github.com/belgattitude/php-java-bridge) I initiated few months ago*), is to build your own jar. As a quick example with jasper and mysql, you can download, unzip and build your own java bridge war with:

  ```
  wget https://github.com/belgattitude/php-java-bridge/archive/7.0.0.zip -O pjb.zip
  unzip pjb.zip && cd php-java-bridge-7.0.0
  ./gradlew war -I init-scripts/init.jasperreports.gradle -I init-scripts/init.mysql.gradle
  ```

> The builded war file will be available in the `./build/libs` folder,
>   ready to deploy.

A more complete installation is located: http://docs.soluble.io/soluble-japha/install_server/#build-and-customize

**2. The error reporting problem.**

The symfony error handler (or whoops...) will not play well with the `Java.inc` client and debugging can really be a mess. I suggest to use the soluble-japha client instead: https://github.com/belgattitude/soluble-japha
which, amongst other things, will throw exceptions in a more standard way, see [here](http://docs.soluble.io/soluble-japha/language_exceptions/).

The `soluble-japha` is just the client part, it replaces the `Java.inc` and is compatible with the official php-java-bridge 6/7 and the soluble php-java-bridge server implementations. You'll have to slighty change you PHP code but nothing very hard. See the [documentation website](http://docs.soluble.io/soluble-japha/).

From there you might have a better view of the problem.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot !! it was very helpful